# SDN4 - Updating a relationship entity's child causes the relationship to be deleted

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I am writing some GraphUnit supported integration tests and have noticed odd behavior when I attempt to update the child node an existing relationship points to.

Given an existing relationship with a backing graph that looks like:

```
(A:ParentNode)-[:SOME_REL {id: 1}]->(B:ChildNode)
```

If I try to update it by writing code like:

```
ChildNode newChildNode = new ChildNode();
existingRelationship.setChild(newChild);
RelationshipRepository.save(existingRelationship);
```

The resulting graph looks like:

```
(A:ParentNode)
(B:ChildNode)
(C:ChildNode)
```

But I expect it to look like:

```
(A:ParentNode)-[:SOME_REL {id: 1}]->(C:ChildNode)
```

The raw log output I see when I execute the GraphRepository `save()` includes a DELETE statement in the Cypher query that drops the relationship:

```
10:32:32.218 [main] DEBUG o.n.o.s.r.SessionRequestHandler - {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH ()-[_0]->() WHERE id(_0)=0 SET _0+={_0_props}  WITH _0 MATCH ($0)-[_1:`SOME_REL`]->($1) WHERE id($0)=0 AND id($1)=1 AND id(_1)=0 DELETE _1","parameters":{"_0_props":{"doubleProp":1.0}},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
10:32:32.219 [main] INFO  o.n.o.session.request.DefaultRequest - POST http://localhost:7475/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH ()-[_0]->() WHERE id(_0)=0 SET _0+={_0_props}  WITH _0 MATCH ($0)-[_1:`SOME_REL`]->($1) WHERE id($0)=0 AND id($1)=1 AND id(_1)=0 DELETE _1","parameters":{"_0_props":{"doubleProp":1.0}},"resultDataContents":["row"],"includeStats":false}]}
```

Is this a bug? Or am I not updating an SDN4 relationship entity properly?  Do we have to delete relationships and create them from scratch each time we effectively want to do an update?

Comment: SOME_REL is backed by a relationship entity in SDN 4? And "existingRelationship" refers to this relationship entity or?

Comment: Yes, it is backed by a relationship entity and has an associated `GraphRepository`.  I've been able to test and prove that my code properly saves the relationship to Neo4j when I am creating it from scratch (using GraphUnit's `printGraph()`)  If any specific code snippets would be helpful in troubleshooting, I am very happy to include them!

Comment: Yes please, if you can share what your relationship entity looks like and the  start/end node entities as well that'll be great. Anything that will help me write a test is welcome. Believe you're using the SDN4 snapshot? If so, are you also using the neo4j-ogm 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Hi Luanne, I've created a contrived project at - https://github.com/simon-lam/sdn-4-demo  The simplified model I have is in there as well as a test case demonstrating the issue - `SimpleRelationshipRepositoryTest`; the assertion is failing AND the output of `printGraph()` is not what I expected.  If it is necessary to take this into JIRA or offline, please let me know!

`./gradlew clean test --debug`

Comment: To answer your other question, no, I am using 1.1.0 of neo4j-ogm.  I am hitting `repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/org/neo4j/neo4j-ogm` and do not see a 1.1.1.SNAPSHOT?

Comment: For anyone else who wants to look at this exact issue, my contrived repo's master branch has been tagged - https://github.com/simon-lam/sdn-4-demo/releases/tag/DATAGRAPH-706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug. The workaround would be to create a new SimpleRelationship with the new end node, replace the existing one on the parent SimpleNode and save the new RE.

The issue can be tracked here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-706

Comment: Update: this is fixed and will be available in the next SDN 4 release

Comment: I've grabbed SDN 4.0.0.RC2 and have retested this and it seems like the issue has been fixed.  However, I did notice that the ID on the relationship entity does change though - is that expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, it would change because it's a new relationship that's created to the new end node. It's not possible to replace the node of an existing relationship, you have to create a new relationship (therefore, new id assigned), and drop the old one.